# PHP, see if date range is partly within another date range

Tags: php, date, date-range

I've been looking forever for this, but the answer seems nowhere. Here's the problem:

Say, I've got two date ranges.

```
$daterange1 = 2012-04-20 till 2012-04-28 
$daterange2 = 2012-04-18 till 2012-05-01
```

Now, I'd like to know if daterange2 is within daterange1. But, as you can see, daterange2 only partly is within daterange1. Is there any way of getting 3 variables back, something like:

1. 2012-04-18 till 2012-04-20
2. 2012-04-20 till 2012-04-28
3. 2012-04-28 till 2012-05-01

I know it sounds a little vague, but I really don't know how to explain it different.

Comment: I understand the question, you may want to convert all the times with the `strtotime()` function and start comparing. Maybe a `DateTime` object will help you here as well.

Comment: do you need to know if the range is within and the 3rd variable

Answer (score 7):

Well, logically you can break down the requirements for a range to be partly in another.

A range is only partly within another range if:

- range1's start date is > than range2's start date but not > than range2's end date
- range1's end date is < than range2's end date but not < than range2's  start date

If either or both of those are true then the ranges are within each other.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example using PHP's `DateTime` class. Note that if you pass an invalid date string to `DateTime::__construct()` the function will throw an exception, so you should implement a try/catch block if you're worried about this. Also, I use PHP's `min` and `max` functions so that it doesn't matter which order the dates are specified.

```
$daterange1 = array('2012-04-20', '2012-04-28');
$daterange2 = array('2012-04-18', '2012-05-01');

$range_min = new DateTime(min($daterange1));
$range_max = new DateTime(max($daterange1));

$start = new DateTime(min($daterange2));
$end = new DateTime(max($daterange2));

if ($start >= $range_min && $end <= $range_max) {
  echo 'woot!';
} else {
  echo 'doh!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a very old post. But still if someone stuck. Here's complete example for overlapping dates.

```
<?php
$daterange1 = array('2017-09-24', '2017-09-28');
$daterange2 = array('2017-09-22', '2017-09-25');

$range_min = new DateTime(min($daterange1));
$range_max = new DateTime(max($daterange1));

$start = new DateTime(min($daterange2));
$end = new DateTime(max($daterange2));

if ($start >= $range_min && $end <= $range_max) {
echo 'Overlapping!';
} 
else if($end > $range_min && $start < $range_max){
echo "partialy";
}
else {
echo 'free!';
}
?>
```