# PHP date function date range

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP, see if date range is partly within another date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717861/php-see-if-date-range-is-partly-within-another-date-range)

I have 2 dates, a start date (2011-01-01) and an end date (2011-02-28).

I have a third date that starts on 2010-01-01 and ends on 2012-03-01.  This means that this third date falls within the first 2 dates range.

If the third dates start and/or end date is not within the 2 dates then it must be false.

How can I check this using php?

Comment: Are you using DateTime objects or just strings?

Comment: I am using timestamps created by using the strtotime() function.

Comment: With an `if` and a few comparisons? What exactly is it that you have a problem with?

Comment: A scenario would be:

A project starts on 2011-01-01 and ends on 2011-10-01.

I would love to calculate the revenue for 2011-05-01 to 2011-05-31. 

How can I tell that the project falls within the period?

Comment: Compare the dates! It doesn't get more basic than that.

Comment: Your "third date" is not a date. A date doesn't start on a one date, and ends on another date.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$startDate = strtotime('2011-01-01');
$endDate = strtotime('2011-02-28');

$intervalStart = strtotime('2011-02-01');
$intervalEnd = strtotime('2012-03-01');


if ($startDate < $intervalStart || $endDate > $intervalEnd) {
    echo 'Not in the interval';
} else {
    echo 'In the interval';
}
```

Comment: The OP has a date *with duration* that needs to be checked.